# Append Div with Multiple Child Divs Using For Loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop

I realize that this has been asked a million times... but sorting through all the ones I've found, I haven't found one that really explains it well.

HTML:

```
<div id="alphabet"></div>
```

JS:

```
var alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", 
                "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];

var target = document.getElementById('alphabet');

for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {

    var newLink = document.createElement('div');
    target.appendChild = newLink;
    newLink.innerHTML = alphabet[i];
}

alert(alphabet);
alert(newLink);
alert(target);
```

Obviously there is something I'm missing... With such a simple example I can't believe I'm having this much trouble. Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically [`node.appendChild(node)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) is a function.

```
target.appendChild(newLink);
```

And your full code would be,

```
for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
 var newLink = document.createElement('div');
 newLink.innerHTML = alphabet[i];
 target.appendChild(newLink);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your complete and swift response. I (hilariously) just made the opposite mistake with the .innerHTML *not* being a function. It is working as intended now. I will mark your answer as accepted once the timer allows me to.

Comment: @perkface Glad to help! :)